# Issue with pulling in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015

We just started to use github in school, and my team's issue is that when I do a pull the new files(classes, etc) are not shown in Visual studio only if I press the show all files button in Solution Explorer, but then I have to include every file manually into the project.
Is there a way to make it automatic? Because it should do it automatically.

Comment: Are you using the Github Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: Files don't get automatically added to projects - when new files are created they should be added to the project, which then gets checked in with the files.

Comment: TFS stores project files. If you add file and check in your changes - everybody will be able to get those. Isn't git does the same?

Comment: I tried the github client, gitshell and now the Github Visual Studio plugin, all did the same, but for some classmates it works like charm

Comment: Did you get a prompt by Visual Studio to reload the projects? Did you click Ignore on this prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when your teammate commited the files, they weren't added to the project (no entry in the .csproj-file).

The .csproj-file is an XML-file which indicates which files are in the project. If he didn't commit the changes to this file, you'll not see them in your project.

Before he commits the changes, he needs to:

- Make sure all the files are included in the project
- Make sure the project is saved to disk (File => Save All) (If he doesn't do this, he'll see the project correctly in solution explorer because it's loading the csproj in memory, but on your end you'll get the old version)

Then he needs to make sure that he commits all files, as well as the .csproj.

If you pull then, it will pull down the newly added files, and the updated project-file

Comment: I see people either not committing the .sln's and .csproj files or often times not actually SAVING their changes in them.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to right click on the files and select include in project to get things going.

Comment: Yes i do that but shouldn't visual studio include them automatically?

Comment: Yes, it should.  But once they are included in the project you should not have to do that again.

Comment: Only if the developer that originally created those files included them in his project at his end, and actually committed the new project file to source control as well. If he created them as part of visual studio (ie. right-click, add new file, etc.), then the question remains if he committed the changed project file as well.

Comment: Also make sure your .gitignore file is not corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure this is a project from VS. Then you have to check in your .csproj and your files will be automatically included to every one.

*.csproj is the responsible to keep the information from what files are from the project.*